# Erdös-Rényi random graphs: Binomial approximation

Tags: random-graphs

I am working on extending the Erdös-Rényi paper "On the evolution of random graphs" (http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1960-10.pdf).
In theorem 2a they calculate the number of isolated trees of order k.

I cannot understand equation (2.13):

$M(\epsilon(S))=\frac{{{n-k \choose 2} \choose N-k+1}}{{n \choose 2} \choose N}=(\frac{2N}{n^2})^{k-1}e^{\frac{-2Nk}{n}}(1+O(\frac{N}{n^2}))$.

In equation (7) they state that they often use:

${n \choose k}\sim\frac{{n^k}e^{-\frac{k^2}{2n}-\frac{k^3}{6n^2}}}{k!}$.

With this I can replicate the first part $(\frac{2N}{n^2})^{k-1}$.

Can someone explain me how to get to the second part $e^{\frac{-2Nk}{n}}$?

Answer (score 0):

With the help of equation (7), it can be written:
\begin{equation}
M(\epsilon(S)) \sim \frac{\binom{n-k}{2}^{N-k+1}}{\binom{n}{2}^N} \frac{N!}{(N-k+1)!} e^{h_{n,N}}
\end{equation}
with $h_{n,N} = O(\frac{N}{n^2})$, so $e^{h_{n,N}}=1+O(\frac{N}{n^2})$. Using the Sterling approximation yields:
\begin{equation}
\frac{N!}{(N-k+1)!} \sim N^{k-1}
\end{equation}
Therefore:
\begin{equation}
M(\epsilon(S)) \sim \frac{\binom{n-k}{2}^{N-k+1}}{\binom{n}{2}^N} N^{k-1} (1+O(\frac{N}{n^2}))
\end{equation}
Now, concerning your question:
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\binom{n-k}{2}^{N-k+1}}{\binom{n}{2}^N} & = & \frac{2^N}{2^{N-k+1}} \frac{(n-k)^{N-k+1}(n-k-1)^{N-k+1}}{n^N(n-1)^N}\\
     & =  & (\frac{2}{n^2})^{k-1} (1-\frac{k}{n})^{N-k+1} (1-\frac{k}{n-1})^{N-k+1}\\
     & \sim  & (\frac{2}{n^2})^{k-1} (1-\frac{k}{n})^N (1-\frac{k}{n-1})^N\\
     & \sim  & (\frac{2}{n^2})^{k-1} (e^{-k})^{\frac{N}{n}} (e^{-k})^{\frac{N}{n-1}}\\
     & \sim  & (\frac{2}{n^2})^{k-1} (e^{-k})^{\frac{N}{n}} (e^{-k})^{\frac{N}{n}}\\
     & =     & (\frac{2}{n^2})^{k-1} e^{\frac{-2Nk}{n}}
\end{eqnarray}
which allows to conclude. Hope this helps despite being a somewhat late answer.

Regards